# How to make eclipse remember ssh key passphrase?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit, passphrase

I'm using Egit with Eclipse to use git and access github. Everything is working fine but one thing that I wish to omit to type `id_rsa` key passphrase everytime I push my commit to github.

I'm asked to enter passphrase each time I restart Eclipse and try to push.

[image: Passphrase Request]

**How can I make eclipse remember passphrase so that I don't have to type manually?**

Thanks

Comment: You could generate a SSH key which does not have a passphrase if all else fails!

Comment: Yes, it's a way but its not a secure option. is it?

Comment: To be fair, if you are worried about security, you should be prepared to put up with the minor extra step of entering your password.

Answer (score 6):

Even if `ssh-add -l` lists your passphrase-protected key, EGit may not honour it and still ask for passphrase.

To integrate with OS keyring on Ubuntu or Mac OS X put

```
export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

to your `~/.bash_aliases` or whenever applicable for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ssh agent.

Add your key to the agent with `ssh-add`. (This will ask you for your passphrase.)

Afterwards the agent should do all the authentication. (No passphrase needed anymore.)

Details:

- try to access your repository manually: `cd $your_repository; git fetch` -> it should ask for your passphrase
- enter `ssh-add -l` -> it should output "The agent has no identities."
- enter `ssh-add` -> it should ask you for your passphrase
- enter `ssh-add -l` -> it should list one identity (the key you just added)
- try to access your repository again: `cd $your_repository; git fetch` -> it should now work without asking for your passphrase
- try to access your repository from eclipse. -> again, no passphrase should be needed.

Comment: Thanks but still I can't figure out how to do it. Can you explain in little more detail?

Comment: `git fetch` didn't ask for my passphrase may be because I've set up to remember passphrase when I'm logged into my ubuntu system. Also `ssh-add -l` shows the key that is added. The problem is only when pushing from `Eclipse`.

Comment: In that case you should raise a bug against egit. (But check first for possible egit options in eclipse.)