# EGit not remembering SSH passphrase

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, eclipse-plugin, egit

Using the terminal `git` command and `RabbitVCS`, I am never asked for my SSH passphrase, since it is added to the SSH agent:

```
me@mymachine:~$ ssh-add -l
2048 s0:m3:f1:ng:3r:pr:1n:7... me@domain.tld (RSA)
```

Anyway, I have issues using EGit with Eclipse. I am prompted for my passphrase when I make an action that requires remote access.

After looking for solutions, I found this SO question: [How to make eclipse remember ssh key passphrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280541/how-to-make-eclipse-remember-ssh-key-passphrase)

Basically I have the same issue. So I tried to set the environment variable, restarted my machine but it just won't work...

```
me@mymachine:~$ echo $GIT_SSH
/usr/bin/ssh
```

(The environment variable is set in .bash-aliases like suggested in the other question)

Since this approach has not worked for me, I was looking for other possible issues which could prevent EGit from using the SSH key from the SSH agent, but in every question/topic/thread setting the environment variable fixed the problem for the people who had the same issue...

- **What can I do to make this running?**
- **What else could lead to this behaviour?**
- **What can I do to debug this?**

Some more information:

- Eclipse: Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- EGit: 4.0.1.201506240215-r (up-to-date)
- Ubuntu: 15.04
- The key was generated using ssh-keygen, and I dont want to use another key or create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that Eclipse was not aware of the `GIT_SSH` environment variable. When I ran Eclipse through the terminal, everything was fine. After I relaunched Eclipse from the Unity side panel, it refused to work again. My fix was to make a custom `eclipse.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse_param.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Contents of `/opt/eclipse/eclipse_param.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -showlocation
```

After these changes, everything worked as expected.